# Descriptive / generative grammar of Mandarin?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, resources

Does anyone know where I can find a descriptive grammar and a generative grammar of Mandarin, in English or French?

Answer (score 1):

The best I know of is *Chinese: A Comprehensive Grammar* (Routledge Comprehensive Grammars) by Yip Po-Ching and Don Rimmington.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese Grammar Wiki

http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/

There are a lot websites about Chinese grammar online, just google for it.

I have a copy of 外国人实用汉语语法, I would say it is a excellent book, but the one I have is of an old edition. Here is the revised edition:

外国人实用汉语语法(修订本)(中英文对照)
A PRACTICAL CHINESE GRAMMAR FOR FOREIGNERS(Revised Edition) (In both English and Chinese)

http://www.amazon.cn/%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA%E5%AE%9E%E7%94%A8%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%AD%E6%B3%95-%E6%9D%8E%E5%BE%B7%E6%B4%A5/dp/B001J0ADWA

Comment: Well actually, I was more looking for something wrote by linguists. Like descriptive or generative grammar, it is a different approach of the language and most of the time way different than prescriptive grammar. But actually your website seems cool for learning purpose.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to a Chinese grammar book.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of Chinese grammar books. I have got one here:

Modern Mandarin Chinese Grammar: A Practical Guide
by Claudia Ross and Jing-heng Sheng Ma
现代汉语实用语法
ISBN: 9780415700108

Sold in Amazon ranging from $30 to $100.

**EDIT:** Tens of various grammar books are listed in Chinese Grammar Wiki. The one above is included.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find it at my university's library. I will try to give you my feedback as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

The article below gives background and development of generative grammars of Chinese, including discussions of germinal research problems and an extensive bibliography containing references to contemporary (1995) generative grammars of Chinese.

C.-T. J. Huang  and  Y.-H. A. Li (eds.) New Horizons in Chinese Linguistics, 49-95.Copyright © 1995 by Kluwer Academic Publishers.

CHAPTER 2 RECENT GENERATIVE STUDIES IN CHINESE SYNTAX

It is available here:

https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/ctjhuang/files/1996.huangli.chap2_.pdf